# max of f64 in Rust

Tags: rust, max

I have a vector of prices (`f64`). I would like to compute the highest price.

What is the current easiest and most idiomatic way to compute the max of a collection of `f64` in rust ?

There has been some discussion about `Ord` and `f64` but I am not sure what is the most up-to-date and less hacky way to do so.

I rely on the following but I imagined there was some built in operation

```rust
let max = prices.iter().fold(None, |r, &n| match r {
    Some(p) => Some(f64::max(p, n)),
    None => Some(e),
});
```

(which is just a fold for some free monoid)

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but: Do _not_ express prices via floating-point types. There are numerous pitfalls you'll never find a way out of. Either express prices via integers (e.g. in cents) or use a full-precision Decimal type.

Comment: not a bad advice ideed...

Comment: Expressing prices at f64 is completely valid, depending on the situation. "Don't do it" isn't comprehensive advice. Prices can and should be expressed in f64 for machine learning and other fast-computation tasks where exact precision isn't required, but of course anything where the value is going to be used for accounting, trading, etc should always use a precise type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of Rust 1.43, you can write this:

```
my_iterator.fold(f64::NEG_INFINITY, f64::max)
```

Explanation: use `f64::NEG_INFINITY` as the initial value, as it is the neutral element for the `f64::max` operation.

Comment: When the iterator is empty, the negative infinity will infect the rest of your code. Depending on the context this may be fine or it may be a problem for downstream processing. I've written code like this before but it's important to make sure that the number crunching you do on the result won't choke on an infinity. Jason's answer has the same issue, but NaNs tend to be even more infectious than infinities and fail in more obvious ways, so that might be better if the iterator is expected to never be empty.

Answer (score 17):

As yet another alternative, since Rust 1.59, there's a [`total_cmp`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.total_cmp) method on `f32` and `f64` that you could use with [`max_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max_by).

```
arr.iter().max_by(|a, b| a.total_cmp(b))
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=%23!%5Bfeature(total_cmp)%5D%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20arr%3A%20%5Bf64%3B%206%5D%20%3D%20%5B1.0%2C%20-42.0%2C%200.0%2C%20-5.0%2C%2042.0%2C%207.0%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20max%3A%20Option%3C%26f64%3E%20%3D%20arr.iter().max_by(%7Ca%2C%20b%7C%20a.total_cmp(b))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20max.unwrap())%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: Looks like total_cmp just got approved so it will probably be in 1.59

Answer (score 13):

I'm unaware of different ways to do so, but I've used the following in the past:

```rust
let arr = [1.0, -42.0, 0.0, -5.0, 42.0, 7.0];
let max = arr.iter().copied().fold(f64::NAN, f64::max) // 42.0
```

Comment: FYI: `copied()` is necessarily as the signature of `f64::max` is `f64::max(f64, f64)`. Without `copied()`, it would be called as `f64::max(f64, &f64)` (which is invalid).

Answer (score 6):

An alternative solution, using the popular [`ordered-float` crate](https://crates.io/crates/ordered-float), allows you to use the built-in `Iterator::max` method:

```
use ordered_float::NotNan; // 2.0.0

let max = arr
    .iter()
    .copied()
    .map(NotNan::new)
    .flatten() // ignore NAN values (errors from the previous line)
    .max()
    .map(NotNan::into_inner);
```

This is essentially the same as the idiomatic code you would write to find the maximum value from an array of integers:

```
let max = arr.iter().copied().max();
```

The difference is that it adds a `NotNan` wrapper around each value, which implements `Ord`. After the result is found, it unwraps the values to get at the inner float. You can apply this pattern to most existing code that works with integers, to update it to work with floats instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a clean way to do it with an actual vector and no copy operation:

```
fn main() {
    let v: Vec<f64> = vec![-2.2, -7.7, -3.3];
    let max = v
        .iter()
        .fold(f64::NEG_INFINITY, |prev, curr| prev.max(*curr));
    assert!(max == -2.2);
    println!("{}", max);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=33d4481fab01bd986cf04626e06a56b0)