# max of a two-dimensional f64 vector in Rust

Tags: image-processing, rust

I want to compute the maximum value of a two-dimensional vector of `f64`s in Rust.
What is the easiest and most performant way to do accomplish this?

My vector is declared as follows:

```rust
let (width,height) = (1920,1080);
let mut flow = vec![vec![0.0; height as usize]; width as usize];
```

My intuitive solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64186095/max-of-f64-in-rust) would be the following: *[(Playground Link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=12ce1538ef76c968be4cbc044e7b1e8d)*

```rust
let max: &f64 = flow.iter()
            .map(|f| f
                .iter()
                .fold(f64::NEG_INFINITY, |prev, curr| prev.max(*curr)))
            .fold(f64::NEG_INFINITY, |prev, curr| prev.max(*curr));
```

However, that code does not compile and only works by converting the iterator of the inner vector into a reference: *[(Playground Link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fdce9c7248fcb757383301506fc1e80a)*

```rust
let max: &f64 = &(flow.iter()
            .map(|f| f
                .iter()
                .fold(f64::NEG_INFINITY, |prev, curr| prev.max(*curr))))
            .fold(f64::NEG_INFINITY, |prev, curr| prev.max(curr));
```

Why do I need to convert the inner iterator into a reference, and is there a better way to find the maximum of a two-dimensional f64 vector?

Comment: Because you define `max` as having type `&f64`. Your first example compiles if you remove the `&` (and the `*` from `*curr`): [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c51377a052f58b127feed54ffc1be27c).

Comment: You're right - Changing `max` into a `f64` fixes the problem - Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to write your loops would be something like this:

```
let max: f64 = flow.iter()
    .map(|f| f
        .iter()
        .fold(f64::NEG_INFINITY, |prev, curr| prev.max(*curr)))
    .fold(f64::NEG_INFINITY, |prev, curr| prev.max(curr));
```

To understand it, it helps to annotate the type of each intermediate value and variables:

```
let max: f64 = flow // Vec<Vec<f64>>
    .iter()         // Iterator<Item=&Vec<f64>>
    .map(|f| f      // f: &Vec<f64>
        .iter()     // Iterator<Item=&f64>
        .fold(
             f64::NEG_INFINITY, // f64
             |prev, curr|       // prev: f64, curr: &f64 -> f64
                    prev.max(*curr)
        )           // return of fold(): f64
    )               // return of map(): Iterator<Item=f64>
    .fold(
         f64::NEG_INFINITY,     // f64
         |prev, curr|           // prev: f64, curr: f64 -> f64
                prev.max(curr)
    )               // return of fold(): f64
    ;
```

Note the signature of [`Iterator::fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold):

```
fn fold<B, F>(self, init: B, f: F) -> B where
    F: FnMut(B, Self::Item) -> B,
```

This means that it returns the type of its first argument, in your case the first argument is always `f64::NEG_INFINITY`.

And in the closure, the first argument is of that same type, while the second is the type of the `Item` from the iterator where `fold` is used. In the first `fold` that `Item` is `&f64` but in the second one it is `f64`.

That is why in the first closure `curr: &f64` while in the second one `curr: f64`, that I think was the most confusing point.

That said, I would write instead:

```
    let max = flow
        .iter()
        .flatten()
        .fold(f64::NEG_INFINITY, |prev, curr| prev.max(*curr));
```

[`Iterator::flatten`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flatten) is a function that applied to an iterator that returns something that implements `IntoIterator<Item=T>` returns a value that implements `Iterator<Item=T>` and that iterates over the whole two-dimensional thing. Exactly what you need, I think.

If you want to get rid of the reference in `curr`, useful if your code in `fold` is more complex, you can also add `copied()`:

```
    let max = flow
        .iter()
        .flatten()
        .copied()
        .fold(f64::NEG_INFINITY, |prev, curr| prev.max(curr));
```

[`Iterator::copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied) just converts an `Iterator<Item=&T>` into an `Iterator<Item=T>`, as long as `T: Copy`.

Comment: Using `flatten()` works perfectly for my use case - thanks for your answer!

Comment: Depending on the situation, [`Iterator::reduce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.reduce) might be slightly more convenient than `fold`, as you can omit the initial value there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how fast this solution is, but it's clearer:

```
let max = flow
    .iter()
    .flatten()
    .max_by(|a, b| a.partial_cmp(b).unwrap());
```

Comment: Rust 1.62 recently added [f64::total_cmp](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.f64.html#method.total_cmp) precisely for these use cases.

Comment: @rodrigo Should we use `total_cmp` when speed is an important aspect of the problem at hand and it is superfluous to deal with the special cases of NaN or positive and negative zero?

Comment: Well, if speed is important you should try both, measure the performance and compare. But I would expect `a.total_cmp(b)` to be faster than `a.partial_cmp(b).unwrap()` if only because it omits the possibility of panics. Maybe even `a.partial_cmp(b).unwrap_or(Ordering::Less)` is faster, who knows?

Comment: @rodrigo The OP wanted the _most performant way_. He should definitely test the variants.